# ExtJS component get the different position from afterrender and focus event?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-mvc

Hi I tried to get component position but I found the `getXY()` will show diffrent position in different events.

like this sample, [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/127d)

```
init: function() {
    var me = this;

    me.control({
        'textfield[itemId=field]': {
            change: me.changeField,
            focus: me.focusField,
            afterrender: me.afterRenderField
        }

    });

},

focusField: function(field, event) {
    console.log(field.getXY());
},

changeField: function(field, newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(field.getXY());
},

afterRenderField: function(field) {
    console.log(field.getXY());
}
```

I think the correct position is in focus and change events. Why afterrender is different?

I want to do something after the component is rendered so I need to get the correct position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the event **[boxready](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-boxready)**

the reason for the difference is event the object is rendered it's not lay out yet.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I want